# OUT OF STACK Error with VBScript recursion in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, function, recursion, vbscript

Let me explain it in detail. so what this code does is, based on the parameter values if 'id'or 'f' is greater than 0 and 'l' or 's' is 6 then it calculates the 3% (2% and 1% in next iterations respectively) of a value (say = P), updates the 'id' and 'l' to something else and and stores it somewhere else. This is to be done until 'id' or 'f' becomes 0 or 'l' or 's' becomes greater than 8.

That is all that it needs to be done. But it calculates up to 2% of the first value and gives the error

```
 Function percentage(f, s, t)
 Dim id, l, k, y
 k = 2
 id = f
 l = s
 y = t
        If id <> 0 Then

           While IsEmpty(Sheet7.Cells(k, 1).Value) = False

               If Sheet7.Cells(k, 1).Value = id Then
                   id = Sheet7.Cells(k, 11).Value
                      If l = 6 Then
                        Sheet7.Cells(k, l).Value = 0.03 * Sheet7.Cells(y, 3).Value
                         l = l + 1
                      ElseIf l = 7 Then
                        Sheet7.Cells(k, l).Value = 0.02 * Sheet7.Cells(y, 3).Value
                         l = l + 1
                       ElseIf l = 8 Then
                        Sheet7.Cells(k, l).Value = 0.01 * Sheet7.Cells(y, 3).Value
                       End If
                End If
                k = k + 1
                Wend
              percentage = percentage(id, l, y)
        End If

  End Function
```

Comment: Is this VBScript or VBA?  If it was VBScript I would expect to see some creation of an Excel Application object somewhere within your code.

Comment: this function is called by a Sub and majority of code lies in the sub and it is very long.. i posted this function because problem lies in the function not in sub

Comment: `If l < 9 Then` is always true (unless `l` >= 9 from the beginning). The highest `l` value you can get is 8.

Comment: Is `Sheet7` a module-level scoped variable?

Comment: I cannot terminate the recursion properly,  can you show me how to end recursion in VBScript using "if  and else" conditions

Comment: ok i will try structuring the loops and conditions better first

Comment: @GauravRajGhimire Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code is well written (i.e. all variables have their values set properly), the only problem I can see is the value of `l` and the condition of `If l < 9 Then`. Possible options are:

- for `l<6` - your code will do nothing and will just loop infinitely. It would be (almost) the same as

  `Function percentage(f, s, t)
      percentage(f, s, t)`
- for `6<=l<=8` - your code will do something (`If/ElseIf` statements) but will still loop infinitely, as the only lines that change the value of `l` are `l = l + 1` which are run only for `l=6` and `l=7`. Hence, the highest `l` value you can achieve is 8.
- for `l>8` - your code will do nothing at all

I don't know what is the purpose of this code, so it's hard to tell how it should be fixed. Maybe adding `l = l + 1` after `ElseIf l = 8 Then` is enough. However, this will fix only the second case. If you start with `l<6` you will still loop forever.

**UPDATE**

Check the code below. I didn't check if values are written in right cells, I guess you can debug it in case something is displayed in wrong way.

```
Function percentage(f, s, t)
Dim id, l, k, y
k = 2
id = f
l = s
y = t

If id <> 0 Then
    If l > 5 And l < 9 Then
        While IsEmpty(Sheet7.Cells(k, 1).Value) = False

            If Sheet7.Cells(k, 1).Value = id Then
                id = Sheet7.Cells(k, 11).Value
                If l = 6 Then
                    Sheet7.Cells(k, l).Value = 0.03 * Sheet7.Cells(y, 3).Value
                    l = l + 1
                ElseIf l = 7 Then
                    Sheet7.Cells(k, l).Value = 0.02 * Sheet7.Cells(y, 3).Value
                    l = l + 1
                ElseIf l = 8 Then
                    Sheet7.Cells(k, l).Value = 0.01 * Sheet7.Cells(y, 3).Value
                    l = l + 1
                End If
            End If
            k = k + 1
        Wend
        percentage = percentage(id, l, y)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Dave Thanks for editing. I have no idea how I didn't realize that.

Comment: there was no error in your code, even with the locations, but I m still getting the same error... the error is in this line  "percentage=percentage(id, l, y)"

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Also, can you provide some simple data to reproduce your problem?

Comment: yaa i tried debugging it too.. nothing seem to be working so i had remove the recursion and replace it with 8 nested loop on the sub.. though it is not a permanent solution.. it is working fine now

Comment: @GauravRajGhimire I just realized... Some devs don't like it but there is still `GoTo` statement.

Comment: @GauravRajGhimire I found a problem in your code, that when `id <> 0` and `Sheet7.Cells(k, 1).Value <> id`, then none of variables changes and next function is called with same arguments. You must add or change your conditions to break the function.

Comment: I had already completed project with other code but I will try it again to see if it works